# How can it be that count(distinct x, y) < # records distinct x, y

Tags: mysql

I'd like to learn why the query

```
select distinct m.id, m.sex 
from   member m
join   household h on m.household_id = h.id
join   contact c on c.household_id = h.id
where  c.contact_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30';
```

returns 923 rows, yet will return the value 918 with the query

```
select count(distinct m.id, m.sex) 
from   member m
join   household h on m.household_id = h.id
join   contact c on c.household_id = h.id
where  c.contact_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30';
```

The query

```
select count(distinct m.id) 
from   member m
join   household h on m.household_id = h.id
join   contact c on c.household_id = h.id
where  c.contact_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30';
```

also returns 923.

The statement `select * from member m where sex not in ('Male', 'Female')` returns no rows.

Comment: Show us the output of `select distinct m.id, m.sex 
from   member m
join   household h on m.household_id = h.id
join   contact c on c.household_id = h.id
where  c.contact_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30' and (m.is is null or m.sex is null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 records with `m.sex is null` I think.

Any operator applied to NULL (except `IS [NOT] NULL` and `<=>`) returns NULL treated as False.